# After deploy django app in digitalocean i can't see my changes in server?

Tags: python, django

I was deploy my webapp in digitalocean which is written by django. Now i change and add some file in it. I change the template folder and also add some photos in static folder. After change i pull the changes from github in my server app directory. But i can't see the changes. I stop the nginx server. I use this command

```
sudo systemctl start nginx 
sudo systemctl stop nginx 
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

then again i start but no changes. what should i do?

Comment: Try to restart uwsgi service.

Comment: I don't use uwsgi service. I use gunicorn and nginx

Comment: If you use gunicorn, so restart it, because nginx doesn't reload Django app.

Comment: did i need to first stop gunicorn then restart ?

Comment: @SergeyPugach thanks bro. But one my page show me Server Error (500). can you please tell me why?. I mean some of pages work and some of pages show me this error?

Comment: It means that there are some errors in your logic. If it's develop server you can set debug as True and you will see an error itself. Otherwise I suggest to add Sentry to your application for handling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to reload Django app restart your `gunicorn` service.

```
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
```

Comment: Thanks bro. Then i get a service error 500. I solved this problem. I just set debug=true and found my error. And did my migrations. Thank you .

Comment: If it solved your problem please upvote my answer and mark it as solution according to StackOverflow rules. Good luck!

Comment: I marked it but i can't upvote because of reputation. sorry bro!.